# What is the "messagebus" user group?

Tags: macos, users

I recently find a new group in my Mac 's "User & Groups"  pref pane.

[image: image1]

Anyone know what happened of my Mac? Is it safe?

MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch,Early 2015), OS X Yosemite (10.10.5)

Comment: [Help: Accounts "Message Bus" and "Policy Kit" apeared in Accounts PrefPane](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2351710)

Comment: Dbus usually runs in that group. Have you installed many apps via Homebrew? A ton of them depend on it.

Comment: @Bandrami Yes, I have installed lots of things like php, svn, libjpeg by `brew install`.